# Codeigniter 3 & SphinxSearch

Tags: php, codeigniter, sphinx, codeigniter-3

I am currently new to codeigniter and am rewriting my website into the Ci3 Framework.

I am currently using Sphinx Search for my site search due to large database.
I am trying to build the Sphinx api into the CI framework but getting stuck and not sure what I am doing wrong.

According to outdated posts in both CodeIgniter & Sphinx Search I simply have to copy the SphinxSearch api into a library in CI and load it into a controller to be pushed out in a view...

When placing the api into a library like follow I get the following error...
Calling the Library in a controller:

```
class Page_Default extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct() 
      {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->helper('url');
         $this->load->database();
         $this->load->model('cat_model');
         $this->load->library('Sphinxclient');
      }
```

The Error:

```
An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested class: Sphinxclient
```

Why is this and what am I doing wrong if my My_Sphinxclient.php library file looks as follow:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/// known searchd commands
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_SEARCH",  0 );
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_EXCERPT", 1 );
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_UPDATE",  2 );
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_KEYWORDS",3 );
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_PERSIST", 4 );
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_STATUS",  5 );
define ( "SEARCHD_COMMAND_QUERY",   6 );

/// current client-side command implementation versions
define ( "VER_COMMAND_SEARCH",      0x116 );
define ( "VER_COMMAND_EXCERPT",     0x100 );
define ( "VER_COMMAND_UPDATE",      0x102 );
define ( "VER_COMMAND_KEYWORDS",    0x100 );
define ( "VER_COMMAND_STATUS",      0x100 );
define ( "VER_COMMAND_QUERY",       0x100 );

/// known searchd status codes
define ( "SEARCHD_OK",              0 );
define ( "SEARCHD_ERROR",           1 );
define ( "SEARCHD_RETRY",           2 );
define ( "SEARCHD_WARNING",         3 );

/// known match modes
define ( "SPH_MATCH_ALL",           0 );
define ( "SPH_MATCH_ANY",           1 );
define ( "SPH_MATCH_PHRASE",        2 );
define ( "SPH_MATCH_BOOLEAN",       3 );
define ( "SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED",      4 );
define ( "SPH_MATCH_FULLSCAN",      5 );
define ( "SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2",     6 );    // extended engine V2 (TEMPORARY, WILL BE REMOVED)
```

............ Rest of file to big to post...

Comment: Have you followed all from docs: i.e. [invoke CI instance](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#utilizing-codeigniter-resources-within-your-library) in your library too?

Comment: !!!! Might be a good starting point!!! I did not include it. ;-)

Comment: Try and let us know. ;)

Comment: I added it to my library like:
code <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class Sphinxclient {

        public $CI;
        public function __construct()
        {
                // Assign the CodeIgniter super-object
                $this->CI =& get_instance();
        } code
**bold**But got the following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'define' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: Try with another sphinxclient class let's say with [this one](https://github.com/gigablah/sphinxphp/blob/master/src/Sphinx/SphinxClient.php). That one you are using has functions and definitions before class itself. Check this one I proposed if you can port it to your code. I think you can remove 'namespace' line if you don't use composer autoload.

Comment: Just to confirm?
I should still add the 
        public $CI;
        public function __construct()
        {
                $this->CI =& get_instance();
        }

Comment: Ok, I did replace all with the one you sent.
And excluded the  public $CI; public function __construct() { $this->CI =& get_instance();
The page now loads and I will do further testing to see if I can port it. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Care to share message? :) Yes, still need `&get_instance()`.

Comment: Yes I did add          $CI =& get_instance();
         $CI->load->library('Sphinxclient'); to my controller.
Share message? You mean going into chat?

Comment: Message of error. What does it say?

Comment: Ah, no that was resolved... I edited my message.
I now want to play around with what I have to see if I can get it to work..
Practice makes perfect... I hope! ;-)

Comment: Read CI docs, it is well explained almost everything. Happy coding.